# Integrability of a function defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $r>0$ and $|\cdot|$ the Euclidean norm.

We consider $f(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\cos(\langle x,y\rangle)e^{-|x|^4+r|x|^2}dx,y\in \mathbb{R}^d.$

How can we prove that $f\in L^1?$

Attempt: I tried computing the integral bit this seems impossible, also tried to write the series expansion of $\cos,$ this lead to no where, since the computation is still difficult

Comment: Denote $\varphi(x)=e^{-|x|^4+r|x|^2}$, then $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$(Schwartz class), so the Fourier transform $\hat\varphi(y)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \varphi(x)e^{-\mathrm{i}x\cdot y}\,dx$ also belongs to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$, hence $\hat\varphi\in L^1$. Therefore $f=\mathrm{Re}\  \hat\varphi\in L^1$.